# NonlinearModelFit failing because varible range

Tags: fitting, constraint

I'm trying to fit a specific equation to a plot of points but its failing because the equation has a square root in it and I need to keep the values of x between a certain range. I know how to do this for the constants but how do I do this for a variable?

```
data = Table[{x, (((x - 1.6)^2)/(16.456*(1 + 
           Sqrt[1 - (1 + 0.65)*((x - 1.6)^2)/(16.456^2)]))) + 
     0.00032*(x - 1.6)^4 + .6554}, {x, -0.65, 4.073, .001}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, (((x - g)^2)/(c*(1 + Sqrt[1 - (1 + k)*((x - g)^2)/(c^2)]))) + 
   c*(x - g)^4 + 
   p, {{a, 0.00032}, {c, 16.456}, {k, 0.65}, {g, 1.6}, {p, .6554}}, 
  x, MaxIterations -> 100]

Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, -0.65, 4.073}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True]
```

I'm telling it exactly where to start and it still can't find the fit.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example including the code and data that can be used to reproduce the problem. Specify clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Post a reduced form of your data points as well. Then we can play ourselves

Comment: Thank you for adding in the example.  You have an error in the formula you placed in `NonlinearModelFit`.  You have `+ c*(x-g)^4` when it should be `+ a*(x-g)^4`.  After making that change everything works fine.  So I would bet money that the question will be closed.  I wish I could say I've never made such a mistake (more than once).

Comment: @JimB Thanks, that fixed that problem but if I change the values to other random values then I get `is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {4501} at {a,c,k,g,p} = \
{1.,1.,1.,1.,1.}.` So what if I don't know where the constants should start at?

Comment: You'll get imaginary numbers anytime $\frac{(k+1) (x-g)^2}{c^2} > 1$ so your starting values should certainly be consistent with that.  $g$ seems to be near where the minimum occurs and $p$ might be the minimum.  Happy guessing!

Comment: @JimB is there a way to state that it must always be less than 1?

Comment: Yes, the documentation shows how to put in restrictions on the parameters.  That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I do believe I'm still on topic, I'm still not able to get a result due to the squareroot. I found nothing in ref/NonlinearModelFit that explains how to add a restriction that is more complicated than just c>0.23. Adding ```((1 + k)*((x - g)^2)/(c^2)) < 1``` after the equation but still in the 'form' section doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE.
I believe the issue  is that `a` is not defined in your model.

I have corrected, so the following should work:

```
data = Table[{x, (((x - 1.6)^2)/(16.456*(1 + 
           Sqrt[1 - (1 + 0.65)*((x - 1.6)^2)/(16.456^2)]))) + 
     0.00032*(x - 1.6)^4 + .6554}, {x, -0.65, 4.073, .001}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, (((x - g)^2)/(c*(1 + Sqrt[1 - (1 + k)*((x - g)^2)/(c^2)]))) + 
   a*(x - g)^4 + 
   p, {{a, 0.00032}, {c, 16.456}, {k, 0.65}, {g, 1.6}, {p, .6554}}, x,
   MaxIterations -> 100]

Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, -0.65, 4.073}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True]
```